# Working with abstract models in cakephp 1.2

Tags: cakephp, abstract, cakephp-1.2, cakephp-model

I'm working on a project based on cakephp 1.2.2.
And I'm having the following situation.
I have a few model classes with the following hierarchy

```
Human_Abstract extends AppModel {
    var $table = 'livingBeing';
}

Man extends from Human_Abstract...
Woman extends from Human_Abstract...
```

suppose all those models need to work with the same table,
How do i do that?
because i have tried with the var $table = 'livingBeing';

but if I try

```
$man = new Man();
$man->findAll(...);
```

The findAll method arranges the query using

```
Man.fields
```

and not using

```
LivingBeing.id
```

So... how can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var $useTable = 'living_being';
```